# Find $7^{1604} \mod28$

Tags: number-theory

How do I find $7^{1604} \mod28$? 7 and 28 aren't coprime, so I can't use Fermat's little theorem. How do I approach that types of problmes? Do I use Chinese Remainder theorem?

Comment: How about calculating $7^{1603}\mod 4$ instead?

Comment: Even, if there might be easier solutions, I always solve such congruences with the chinese remainder theorem. So I would suggest to do that. Another possibility is to use the Carmichael function. Here, the chinese remainder theorem almost immediately gives the solution.

Comment: $7^1 \equiv 7 \pmod {28} $, $7^2 \equiv 21 \pmod {28} $, but $7^3 \equiv 7  \pmod {28}$ so the pattern repeats...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach to problems with a fixed number to take modulo of is to break the number up to prime powers. In your case, you break $28$ up to $7\times 2^2$.

Next, use CRT to convert the problem to 2 subproblems, investigating the remainder modulo 7 and 4. The first one is obvious, you just get 0. What about the second one? Can you use Fermat's little theorem?

Don't forget to put everything together with CRT when you're done!

Answer (score 0):

Using elementary math, $$7^{1604}=28q+r$$ so $r$ is divisible by $7$,

$$7^{1603}=4q+(r/7)$$

But $7=-1$ modulo $4$, so $7^{1603}=4m-1$. Hence $$r=7(r/7)=28-7=21$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, use the *Chinese remainder theorem*,  more precisely the formula for the inverse isomorphism of
\begin{align}
\varphi:\mathbf Z/28\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/7\mathbf Z,\\
n\bmod 28&\longmapsto (n\bmod 4,n\bmod7),
\end{align}
which is deduced from a Bézout's relation between $4$ and $7$:
$2\cdot 4-7=1$,
$$\varphi^{-1}(x\bmod 4,y\bmod 7)=[y\cdot2\cdot 4-x\cdot 7] \bmod 28.$$